Jesus Christ's resurrection & justification In Isaiah 59:16 (b-c) "Then His own arm brought salvation to Him, And His righteousness upheld Him."

Isaiah 59:16
New American Standard Bible 1995
16 And He saw that there was no man, And was astonished that there was
no one to intercede;
( b ) Then His own arm brought salvation to Him,
( c ) And His righteousness upheld Him.
17 He put on righteousness
like a breastplate, And a helmet of salvation on His head; And He put
on garments of vengeance for clothing And wrapped Himself with zeal as
a mantle.


59:16-17 The Westminster Leningrad Codex 16 וַיַּרְא֙ כִּֽי־אֵ֣ין
אִ֔ישׁ וַיִּשְׁתּוֹמֵ֖ם כִּ֣י אֵ֣ין מַפְגִּ֑יעַ וַתּ֤וֹשַֽׁע לוֹ֙
זְרֹע֔וֹ וְצִדְקָת֖וֹ הִ֥יא סְמָכָֽתְהוּ׃
17 וַיִּלְבַּ֤שׁ צְדָקָה֙ כַּשִּׁרְיָ֔ן וְכ֥וֹבַע יְשׁוּעָ֖ה
בְּרֹאשׁ֑וֹ וַיִּלְבַּ֞שׁ בִּגְדֵ֤י נָקָם֙ תִּלְבֹּ֔שֶׁת וַיַּ֥עַט
כַּמְעִ֖יל קִנְאָֽה׃

I might just be asking the obvious.
From my perspective, Isaiah 59:16 (b) mentioning of how God’s own Arm brought salvation to Himself can be a reference to God’s own arm bringing salvation to Jesus Christ who is God by resurrecting Jesus Christ three days after His crucifixion.
Furthermore, Isaiah 59:16 ( c )  mentioning of how God righteousness upheld Jesus Christ who is God is God’s justification for raising Jesus Christ from death.
I’m just asking because while I was searching the internet to search for articles and internet postings regarding Isaiah 59:16 (b-c) reference to Jesus Christ’s resurrection, I did Not find anything on the internet.
Therefore, Is Isaiah 59:16 (b-c) referring to Jesus Christ’s resurrection after he was crucified?

It would be good if the Title matched the actual question.

The context of the rest of Isa 59 is simply a lament about the general and all-pervasive sinfulness and sinful inclinations of mankind.
V16 is a pivot - essentially, the LORD is wondering what to do to save mankind from the general sinfulness and "discovered" that there was no man who could save mankind.  Therefore, the LORD decides to do it Himself.
In this sense, V16 is a record of the LORD deciding to become the Savior of humanity.  That is, the LORD becomes Messiah.  This is in keeping with other texts that teach the same thing:

Isa 43:3 - For I am the LORD your God, the Holy One of Israel ...
Isa 43:11 - I, yes I, am the LORD, and there is no Savior but Me
Isa 44:24 - Thus says the LORD, your Redeemer who formed you from the womb
Isa 45:21 - ... Was it not I, the LORD? There is no other God but Me, a righteous God and Savior; there is none but Me.
Isa 49:7 - Thus says the LORD, the Redeemer and Holy One of Israel ...

I do not see a reference in Isa 59:17 to the resurrection of Christ.  It is in the NT that we are taught that this Savior of mankind is called "Jesus", Matt 1:21; Acts 4:12; 2 Tim 1:10; Tit 1:4, 2:13, 3:6; 2 Pet 1:1, 11.

The Book of Isaiah in the Bible is known for the fact that it prophesizes about Messianic Savior's life.  Isaiah 53 is just one of the many examples of the prophecies.  Therefore,  Isaiah 59:16 (b-c) can be broadly viewed as emphasizing the Messiah's(Jesus Christ) justification & resurrection.
